# Is it faster to use a lookup table or to left/right bit-shift to obtain a power of 2 integer?

Tags: performance, x86, bit-manipulation

Suppose I want to build the bit mask with the Nth bit set. I have N as an integer.

Which is better? `1 << N` or a lookup table (pointer arithmetic addition)?

My guess is that a single bit shift operation is faster than a memory lookup, and only once cache-hot does LUT have a fighting chance. However if this is the case then why are LUT's so often the fastest solution in bit-twiddling problems? Is it simply because of the huge caches we have in our CPU's these days?

Let me qualify the question with the fact that I care the most about this operation at this moment on x86-64.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit shift will always be far faster than either a look-up table or a calc.

Comment: So it is even faster than an addition? impressive.

Comment: @Steven Lu bit shift to CPU is what moving the decimal point is to humans. No wonder why it is so fast.

Comment: @Steven You can do addition at the bit level & yes it would be faster. But the the speed gain would not typically be be worth the effort. Start talking powers of 2 though and there is no contest.

Comment: Do you have any URL with evidence of x86 performance of bit-shift (given a variable N with amount to shift) and a table lookup?  Your statement sounds correct to me, but what is the evidence?

Answer (score -3):

Are you sure? I ran this VB program and the results were a bit variable, but lookup was usually quicker than bit shifting, and not much higher than the null time. This is probably because of caching, so it's hard to generalise from this.

I got a similar result from a random shift value, but of course the random number generation was taking longer than anything else.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim SW As New Stopwatch()
Dim TimeShift As Long
Dim TimeLookUp As Long
Dim Timenull As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim Bit As UInteger
Dim R As New Random()
Dim total As UInteger
Dim S = New System.Text.StringBuilder()

total = 0
SW.Start()
j = 0
For i = 1 To RepCount
  Bit = CUInt(1) << (j And 31)
  j += 1
  'Bit = 1 << (R.Next(31))
  total = total Or Bit
Next
SW.Stop()
TimeShift = SW.ElapsedMilliseconds

SW.Reset()
SW.Start()
For i = 1 To RepCount
  Bit = Bits(j And 31)
  j += 1
  'Bit = Bits(R.Next(31))
  total = total Or Bit
Next
SW.Stop()
TimeLookUp = SW.ElapsedMilliseconds

SW.Reset()
SW.Start()
For i = 1 To RepCount
  total = total Or (j And 31)
  j += 1
Next
SW.Stop()
Timenull = SW.ElapsedMilliseconds

If Stopwatch.IsHighResolution Then
  S.Append("High")
Else
  S.Append("Low")

End If
S.Append(" frequency clock")
S.AppendLine()
S.Append("Shift time= " & TimeShift & " ms")
S.AppendLine()
S.Append("Lookup time= " & TimeLookUp & " ms")
S.AppendLine()
S.Append("Null time=" & Timenull & " ms")
S.AppendLine()
S.Append("Total= " & total.ToString)

MsgBox(S.ToString)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hey Peter, please don't take my previous comment the wrong way. I think it's really great that you contributed this thought. For one, it's truly an "off the beaten path" answer, especially today, in 2014. The main reason why I made the comment was that the Visual Basic language simply has no bearing on the original question that I asked. If anything at all, the answer is a non-sequitur to me. Nobody would, or should, in my very humble opinion, ever be in a situation in which they should concern themselves with the performance between use of a LUT and bit-shift ops, with VB (pragmatically).

Comment: Well, there's a bug in my program - it doesn't reset the stopwatch at the end. Repairing this makes bitshift come out quicker. WHich is what I'd have thought. Memo to self - if the answer isn't what you want, check the program. And your initial posting didn't specify language. And what's wrong with VB if you want to write a quick & dirty program for displaying something in a window (which is what I was doing when I needed bit shifts and came across this thread)?

Comment: @Peter: On the one hand, I'll have to agree with Steven Lu on this:  responding to a question about performance on x86 with an answer in a .Net language is a non sequitur. Truly high performance code would be written in a native language (C++, C), not a "managed" / GC'd language (C#, VB, Java). On the other hand, I have a VB program where it isn't worth linking to some higher performance solution, so it was interesting to see your comparison. But the way your tests are written, there is too much time spent in loop overhead, and in incrementing j - not a good comparison...

Comment: ... For more accurate comparison, you should do at least 10 repetitions of the key instruction(s) in each loop.  Something like `j = 15 : For i = 1 To RepCount : total = (1 << j) Or (1 << j) Or (1 << j) Or (1 << ) .. : Next`. Make sure the key operation, `(1 << j)`, is executed many more times than other stuff. The null comparison would be `total = j Or j Or j ..`.

Comment: Steve - take your point about language. But there's an issue with your example - an optimising compiler will notice that (1<<j) or (1<<j) is the same as (1<<j), and remove the extra items. Most compilers these days are better coders than humans.